# NSView -draw method called multiple times

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit

I have a `NSScrollView` with embedded `NSClipView` and `NSView`. Nothing extraordinary. But when I change `NSScrollView.magnification` to something bigger than small, `NSView.draw(_ dirtyRect:NSRect`) is called from somewhere more then one time. 
For `magnification = 0.2` `-draw` is called just one time:

```
refresh 20.0%
visible rect: (-2634.99999999952, -812.500000000788, 5769.99999999869, 2625.00000000089)
drawing... (-250.0, -500.0, 1000.0, 2000.0)
```

`refresh = magnification * 100`

`visible rect:` - taken from `NSClipView.documentVisibleRect`

`drawing...` - prints `dirtyRect` on the beginning of `-draw` method

for .magnification = 1.0 — six times:

```
refresh 100.0%
visible rect: (-327.0, 237.5, 1154.0, 525.0)
drawing... (0.0, 0.0, 750.0, 1024.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 0.0, 250.0, 1024.0)
drawing... (-250.0, -500.0, 250.0, 500.0)
drawing... (0.0, -500.0, 750.0, 500.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 1024.0, 250.0, 476.0)
drawing... (0.0, 1024.0, 750.0, 476.0)
```

for 2.0... hard to count:

```
refresh 200.0%
visible rect: (-38.5, 368.75, 577.0, 262.5)
drawing... (384.0, 256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 512.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 512.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 512.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 512.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 512.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 512.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 640.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 640.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 640.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 640.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 640.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 640.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 128.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 256.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 384.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 512.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 640.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 128.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 256.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 384.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 512.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 640.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 0.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 0.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 0.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 0.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 0.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 0.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 0.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 0.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 768.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 768.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 768.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 768.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 768.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 768.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 768.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 768.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, -128.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, -128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, -128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, -128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, -128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, -128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, -128.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, -128.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 896.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 896.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 896.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 896.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 896.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 896.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 896.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 896.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, -256.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, -256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, -256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, -256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, -256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, -256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, -256.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, -256.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 1024.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 1024.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 1024.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 1024.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 1024.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 1024.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 1024.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 1024.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, -384.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, -384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, -384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, -384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, -384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, -384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, -384.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, -384.0, 110.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-250.0, 1152.0, 122.0, 128.0)
drawing... (-128.0, 1152.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (0.0, 1152.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (128.0, 1152.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (256.0, 1152.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (384.0, 1152.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (512.0, 1152.0, 128.0, 128.0)
drawing... (640.0, 1152.0, 110.0, 128.0)
```

If I will set `magnification = 10.0`, (1000%) `-draw` is called many, many, many times.

Is it some way to avoid it?

I check all `-needsDisplay` in my app, and I'm sure they're not responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: This seems like an interesting problem to explore, but I’m not sure if I completely understand your question. Would it be possible for you to post a minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Ok. I will do it. I need few days, I’m out now.

Comment: I pushed some example project to https://github.com/typoland/TestScrollView . As far I understood draw(rect) loops by parts of NSView. So if each time it has to check what to draw it takes years if objects are complicated. But i still done know how to set redraw in particular area.

Comment: @Łukasz Did you find any solution?

Comment: I discover if area of clipped view becomes bigger than view, draw mthod is called by tiles. You can check if your object should be drawn in particular tile and do it or not.